# Graph/Chart suggestions. Using PHP, jQuery - silverlight?

Tags: php, jquery, silverlight, graph, charts

I'm programming a site using PHP, mysql and jQuery. I would really appreciate and hoping for some suggestions as to what I can use to create pie, bar and line charts, where I have the ability to change the actual graphic thats being shown. For example, if I wanted to have the bar graph use an army camouflage graphic and another one with flower pixels. I've done some looking around, but always found it helpful asking others for what they use or have seen.

Also any recommendations to using silverlight for this over any existing PHP and jQuery extensions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like PHP GD has a function called imagesettile (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesettile.php) that could work. I'm open for other suggestions.

Comment: Isn't Silverlight dead yet? `;)`. There's definitely a shift away from this approach, afaict, so for charts I'd either render on the server (web search for "php charts") or on the client ("html5 charts" or "jquery charts"). I'm sure there are loads of libraries out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would do you good to check out [FusionCharts XT](http://www.fusioncharts.com/products/suite/fusioncharts-xt/). It renders charts in JavaScript, which means your charts will work very well on iOS devices too.

With Silverlight, iOS devices are out.

FusionCharts XT can be used with jQuery too, with jQuery's syntax : http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?jQuery/Overview.html

Answer (score 1):

As you're working with jQuery right now I think these must be good libraries for your use. Besides, the jQuery would extend your page's size up to 77kbs so try to use all benefits of it.

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/

http://www.jqplot.com/